# Torch tensor randomly contains huge, impossible values

Tags: python, machine-learning, torch

I'm new to PyTorch and I'm trying to debug my code using IntelliJ PyCharm. I have a line that logs the content of a torch.IntTensor

```
logger.debug(f"action_tensor    = {action_tensor}")
```

Most of the time this seems to work just fine, but occasionally the print out shows one or several huge values in the tensor, such as:

```
2021-08-06 09:21:17,737 DEBUG main.py state_tensor = tensor([2089484293,          0,          0,          1,          0,          1,
                 1,          0,          0,          0,          0,          0,
                 0,          1,          1,          1,          1,          1,
                 1,          1,          1,          2,          2,          0,
                 0,          0,          0,          0,          0,          6,
                 0,          0,          0,          0,          0,          0,
                 0,          0,          0,          0,          0],
       dtype=torch.int32)
```

The tensor is created by extracting a few values from the state of an object

```
rolls = int(self.rolls)
allowed = [int(self.scorecard[c]["allowed"] == True) for c in self.scorecard]
scored = [int(self.scorecard[c]["score"]) if self.scorecard[c]["score"] else int(0) for c in self.scorecard]
return torch.cat([torch.IntTensor(rolls),
                  torch.IntTensor(allowed),
                  torch.IntTensor(scored)])
```

I've checked multiple times, and there is no way any of these values are as large as the example above (e.g. `2089484293`). I've tried just creating a numpy array instead of a tensor, and print that shows no problems.  I'm suspecting there is something I don't know about how torch.IntTensor.

What is wrong with the way I create my tensor that results in these huge values appearing sometimes?

Comment: What is `self.rolls`?  afaik, 'Rolls' aren't a thing in PyTorch (there is `torch.roll` but that is an operation on a tensor. Are you defining a custom function? If so, please share some context where `self.rolls` comes from

Comment: Sorry for lack of calrity. That function is unrelated :) It's just an integer. I'm suspecting the problem is with tensor.IntTensor. If instead of using torch here I use numpy the arrays end up fine. So something happens when consuming the values with torch.IntTensor.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you pass an int directly to `torch.Tensor`, it will make a tensor of that length with 0 values. So if `rolls = 5` then `torch.IntTensor(rolls)` would become  `tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=torch.int32)`. Trivial solution would be to wrap rolls as `[rolls]`

Comment: @SamarthBhatia thank you! That explains some of the strange behavior! :) Not the huge values, but other things.